# MVVMCrosscore binding issue tableview, collection

Tags: mvvmcross

Following is the Observable collection which is available in the viewmodel:

```
ObservableCollection<Category> productcat;
```

further split of Category class is as follows:

```
public class Category
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set;}
    public List<ProductData> Products
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

ProductData class as follows:

```
public class ProductData
{
     public string ProductImageUri { get; set;}
     public string ProductTitle { get; set;}
     public float productcost { get; set;}
}
```

Part 1:
Now I have  UIScrollView where each Scrollbar item is a button item, containing title as the CategoryName.
I want to do the binding of CategoryName from the observable collection- to each scrollbar button title
Whenever the collection changes the buttons in the UISCrollView titles must reflect the change. **What would be the binding expression in this case given the above class structures. Its challenging to figure out binding syntax.**

Part 2:
I have a UITableView which would contain a cell having product title, product image and product cost, which means i have list
I want to bind this UITableView to this list which is part of Observable Collection->CategoryName->ProductData list
**What would be the binding expression in this case.** I hope we must do custom binding here.?

Yes as you said MvxTableViewCell etc., are available.

And regarding custom binding should I do it in the minisetup?

Comment: Please try to ask one question at a time. Please also include things like "a code sample that someone could build and run" and "compilation and exception error messages". Please try to make it easier for others to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### view models/data structures

In your data structures, you seem to be binding public fields instead of public properties.

These won't work straight away - you need to use properties

So:

```
 public string CategoryName;


 public class ProductData
 {
  public string ProductImageUri;
  public string ProductTitle;
  public float productcost;
 }
```

need to become:

```
 public string CategoryName {get;set;}


 public class ProductData
 {
  public string ProductImageUri {get;set;}
  public string ProductTitle {get;set;}
  public float productcost {get;set;}
 }
```

#### I am not able to find any of these classes: MvxCollectionViewSource, MvxTableViewCell, MvxCollectionViewController etc

`MvxCollectionViewSource` and `MvxTableViewCell` should be available in `MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.dll`

`MvxCollectionViewController` is not available - it's an MvvmCross View

#### In this case how can I achieve binding in CrossCore environment?

This is shown in the N+1 N=39 tutorial - http://slodge.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/n39-crosslight-on-xamariniosmonotouch.html - with source in https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-39-CrossLight-Touch

#### Also I should be able to do custom bindings?

Yes

#### But I am not having any setup class.. in my case. How can achieve custom binding in this case?

As shown in the N+1 N=39 tutorial, you still have a setup class - so you can put your initialization code in there. After the binding builder has been initialized, you can access the `IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry` using `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry>()`

Because you are not using MvvmCross - because you are **choosing** to build your own framework - then ensuring setup is done is your own job to do.

#### What I am currently doing is have a view class and derive the view from IMvxBindable that's all and doing some binding in it

I have no idea what this means - please try including a working code sample in your questions.

Comment: Hi Stuart I had changed details in my query.. can you have a look. Thanks for your support

Comment: Please return your question to it's original question. Then ask new, good questions for each new question you have. On stackoverflow you shouldn't just delete your previous question and then ask new ones in the same place. This is a q&a site - you can use it to ask great questions and get great answers.

Comment: I had posted the one with full code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813685/binding-mvvmcrosscore-tableview-nullreference-exception

Comment: **Please return your question to it's original question.** Then ask new, good questions for each new question you have. On stackoverflow you shouldn't just delete your previous question and then ask new ones in the same place. This is a q&a site - you can use it to ask great questions and get great answers.